# how to make tabulator table cell to accept only numbers and its should not allow to enter non numeric

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tabulator

Here is my table code and i want to retscit table to accept only numbers not any special characters

```js
 

table headers and table definition's 
 this.beltTabulatorHeaders = [
            {
                title: "Type", field: "name", headerHozAlign: "left", width: "55%", headerSort: false, hozAlign: "left", editable: false

            },
            {
                title: "Value", headerHozAlign: "center", width: "45%",
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "Min", field:"minValue",cellEdited: validateBelt, validator:numericValidator,editable:editCheck,editor: "input", headerSort: false, width: "15%", hozAlign: "right", formatter:
                            decimalFormatter
                        , headerHozAlign: "right"
                        , editorParams: {
                            formatter: decimalFormatter,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Nom", field: "nomValue",cellEdited: validateBelt, editor: "input", headerSort: false, width: "15%", hozAlign: "right", formatter: decimalFormatter, headerHozAlign: "right"

                        , editorParams: {
                            formatter: decimalFormatter
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Max", field:"maxValue",cellEdited: validateBelt, editable:editCheck,editor: "input", headerSort: false, width: "15%", hozAlign: "right", formatter: decimalFormatter, headerHozAlign: "right"

                        , editorParams: {
                            formatter: decimalFormatter
                        }
                    },
                ],
            },

        ];
        this.beltTabulatorTable = new Tabulator("#beltTabulatorTable", {
            maxHeight: "100%",
            maxWidth: "100%",
            data: beltTableData,
            layout: "fitDataTable",
            headerSort: false,
            columns: this.beltTabulatorHeaders,
            responsiveLayout: false,
        })
```

above is table code

Comment: @timur can u check this .. is there any way to do other than using  validator

Comment: can you try to use this? `editorParams: {
        type: "number", // Use type="number" to restrict input to numbers
        step: "any", // Allow decimal numbers if needed
    },`? for your inputs? or using validator: `function numericValidator(cell, value) {
    const numericRegex = /^[0-9]+$/;    
    if (!numericRegex.test(value)) {
        return "Please enter a valid numeric value.";
    }
    return true;
}`